# How to get Generic class<T> name of typescript?

Tags: typescript

My Generic class

```
 export class BaseService<T> {
 public subUrl;
 constructor(public repo:RepogitoryService) { }
}
```

How can I store the class name of T on a local variable?

Answer (score 28):

You must understand that Typescript is just a transpiler (compiler to javascript). Some of the syntax sugar (such as generics) are working only in type-checking phase (and also it's helpful for intellisense in your IDE/text-editor).

However assignment to a variable is happening in runtime, in runtime it's just a plain Javascript. There are no types and no generics in runtime.

But here's the easiest way I would do it:

```
class Some<T> {
    private TName : string;
    constructor(x : T&Function) {
        this.TName = x.name;
    }
}

class Another {

}

const some = new Some<Another>(Another);
```

Comment: Why TName is private? How to access some.TName? Incomplete answer it seems to me.

Comment: @hakan OP asked how to store the generic type name as a local variable, which is exactly what this code does. That variable's visibility is irrelevant to the original question.

Comment: This does not seem to work if `Another` had some fields in it.

Answer (score 24):

[durisvk10](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7714992/durisvk10) workaround covers the topic, just want to add that I would rather use 
 `x: new () => T` 
than `x: T&Function`.

Like this:

```
...
constructor(x : new () => T) {
    this.TName = x.name;
}    
...
```

Comment: Please explain this

Comment: You cannot use generics in method body, as it was explained by durisvk10, it's working only in type-checking phase. However you can pass type as argument to your method (constructor in this particular case). And by using this type notation you tells type checker that you expect here type (new () => T) which describes a type with an empty constructor. You can read more about this [here](https://blog.rsuter.com/how-to-instantiate-a-generic-type-in-typescript/) and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Comment: This is quite nice.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot, unfortunately. Typescript is a static type checker and has no support for type reflection at runetime such as java does. This is because its sources are transpiled to javascript.

However, there is hope for such support in the future, with a new typescript feature called "custom transformers". Those transformers are plugins that hook the transpilation process, opening the road to rich features regarding type reflection. A first example of such is [`ts-transformer-keys`](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys).

Comment: It wouldn't need runtime type checking. It has a compilation stage that could insert a string value for a type...

Comment: In fact, I've built that transformer. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71244450/1995204

Answer (score 5):

Cast the object to `Object` and get constructor name?

```
function nameOf(object: Object): string {
    return object.constructor.name;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Typescript removes all type information in the emitted Javascript (and thus at runtime), but thanks to Typescript's "transformers" feature, it is now possible to write a transformer to expose this information at runtime. I have done just that, see https://typescript-rtti.org/ - No decorators required, and it is far more comprehensive than emitDecoratorMetadata