How to conditionally branch on multiple argument types
Here's my code
class ImmutableArraySlice<Type> implements Iterable<Type>
{
    private _source: Array<Type>;
    private _start: number;
    private _end: number;

    constructor(from: Array<Type> | ImmutableArraySlice<Type>, start: number = 0, end?: number)
    {
        this._source = ( /* check if type of 'from' is ImmutableArraySlice */ ) ? from._source : from;
        this._start = start;
        this._end = end ?? source.length;
    }
    ...
}

The problem is that I need to assign different things to this._source based on the input type, but I don't know how to do it. I couldn't google it as I can't formulate this well enough and, as far as I know, you can't have multiple constructors in JS/TS, so I'm out of luck here too
EDIT 1: Made changes to code to further clarify what my goals are (yes, this wasn't as obvious as I thought, my bad)

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312116/how-to-get-generic-classt-name-of-typescript

Type informations is not available at runtime (as typescript is executed as javascript, which does not known about class names in general). But depending on the different types, you may distinguish them by the provided "interface". e.g. not every objec does have a property ".length". (For this you need to think in "Interfaces", which a type needs to provide. In case you are familiar with C# the standard library uses this Interface-concept for list, "IEnumerable", ...).

Are the types primitive (like number and string) or objects?

If what you want to assign _source depends on whether from is a ImmutableArraySlice as well, why not just check the instance? Something like this._source = from instanceof ImmutableArraySlice ? from._source : from. FYI instanceof is a JavaScript operator and has nothing to do with TypeScript.

Now that we understand what you want, yes, instanceof is right, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question or are we missing something?

Yes. As was mentioned by both moonstar-x and jcalz, using instanceof was the solution I needed
Here's the full code snippet I have now in case anyone else stumbles on this issue:
class ImmutableArraySlice<Type> implements Iterable<Type>
{
    private _source: Array<Type>;
    private _start: number;
    private _end: number;

    constructor(from: Array<Type> | ImmutableArraySlice<Type>, start: number = 0, end?: number)
    {
        const is_slice = from instanceof ImmutableArraySlice;
        this._source = (is_slice) ? from._source : from;
        this._start = (is_slice) ? from.start + start : start;
        this._end = (is_slice) ? from.start + (end ?? from.length) : from.length;
    }
    ...
}

